# Instalação do Prestashop

Tags: e-commerce

Tentei instalar o Prestashop e ocorreu o seguinte erro: Fileinfo extension is not enabled
Obs: Meu Cpanel não tem a opção de habilitar essa função no painel Software.

Comment: Olá, Não sei se já resolveu sua questão, mas achei esse link que pode ajudar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795149/htaccess-enable-php-fileinfo-extension Alguns hosts permite a edição disso no php.ini ou entao por .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Quer dizer que seu espaço de hospedagem não possui habilitado a extensão (biblioteca) php_fileinfo.dll para a versão de PHP que está usando.

O curioso é que a partir da versão 5.3 do PHP, esta extensão vem habilitada por padrão, antes disso esse recurso era uma extensão em PECL, mas foi descontinuado. Portanto penso em duas situações:

1. Sua versão do PHP é muito antiga, então veja qual versão está usando
   e se possível atualize-a (ex: 5.6+).
2. Sua hospedagem desabilitou essa extensão, entre em contato com eles
       para que isso seja corrigido.

Se você quiser tentar ativar essa extensão por conta própria, habilite (retire o ;) da expressão "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" dentro do seu arquivo php.ini. Se não conseguir, você pode não ter ele instalado como módulo, então instale-o copilando o PHP novamente pelo EasyApache, mas isso só funciona se você tiver acesso ao WHM.

Boa sorte.